# How can I save Neo4j output graph into a PNG or SVG file using only the terminal/command line?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

am using the Neo4j Driver Web Browser, and when I execute any command, it gives me the option to download an SVG or PNG file. I want to download this PNG or SVG file only using Neo4j in the command line, not with the GUI browser. Can you please help me with this?

I am trying to find a command in Neo4j Driver that can save the output graph into a PNG or SVG file using the terminal/command line.

Answer (score 0):

The [Neo4j Browser](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/) and a [Neo4j Driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/bolt/current/neo4j-drivers/) are two different things.

Since the Neo4j Browser can display visualizations, it can provide ways to download image captures of those visualizations.

But the Driver API has no visualization capabilities. So it does not make sense to expect it to provide any means to download image captures.

[UPDATE]

Neo4j documents a number of [non-neo4j graph visualization tools](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/graph-visualization/graph-visualization/#other-vis) that you may find useful.

Comment: Thank you. I want to display my data as a graph in my Node.js application. Therefore, I believe the most suitable way to accomplish this is by using the D3.js library.

Comment: See my answer update for a link to some non-neo4j graph visualization tools.